# Extracting SMM (SMI) handlers from BIOS flash image

Tags: hardware, disassembly, firmware, bios, systemmanagement

I can download updated BIOS firmware from motherboard producer site. The image of "BIOS Flash" will be downloaded.

Is it possible to find a SMM (SMI) handlers code in the BIOS image? Should I run the BIOS under BOCHS to get this?

PS SMM is system management mode (interrupt), which is used to simulate some not-implemented-in-hardware parts of motherboard.

Comment: may be here http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=66&id=11 "SMI handlers is a
part of BIOS system firmware and can be disassembled similarly to any BIOS
code. " BIOS Disassembly Ninjutsu Uncovered or
  Pinczakko's Guide to Award BIOS Reverse Engineering
  Darmawan M Salihun aka Pinczakko
  http://www.geocities.com/mamanzip/Articles/Award_Bios_RE/Award_Bios_RE_guide.html
  http://www.geocities.com/mamanzip/Articles/award_bios_patching/award_bios_patching.html

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.  The code in the ROM image may well be compressed, and that would make the task of finding the SMI handler even more difficult.  Then there is the fact that there are likely several hundred KBytes of object code in the image that you'd have to search through...

Comment: If assume unpacked image, what I need search for?